# How's this phrase about a housing bubble in the Economist 'an elegant turn of phrase' ? (2015 Jan)

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [CBC News](http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/overvalued-housing-prices-and-how-to-read-them-don-pittis-1.2898003), by Don Pittis

> It is easy to say in retrospect that the results were predictable. But it was the following line in the story that made me sit up and think of Canadian houses.
>
> "The potency of a bubble is its plausibility, to laypeople and experts alike, right up until the moment the `game` is over," [the Economist writer said](http://www.economist.com/news/christmas-specials/21636506-how-childrens-hobby-turned-classic-financial-mania-baseball-card-bubble) in **an elegant turn of phrase**.

1. I consulted ODO's definition of [**turn of phrase**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/turn-of-phrase?q=turn+of+phrase), but what's the '**turn of phrase**' here? Is the Economist writer just saying: a bubble's strength derives from the  possibility, of the existence of a bubble, until the market^ (substituting by `game`, but see 2.) is over.

2. What formal terms describe this use of `game` to imply market? Is it [metonymy and/or synecodoche](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/15567/50720)?

Comment: The turn of phrase is probably "The potency ... is its plausibility". 'Game' may be regarded as a *metaphor* for market speculation--unless of course you take *game* in its old sense of *gambling*, in which case it is merely a factual characterization.

Comment: @StoneyB Sorry, still confused. What's so special or elegant about that sentence? The interpretation of 'game' as a METAPHOR for market speculation? (Pardon the caps; I find them easier to read than italics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Turn of phrase" refers to the choice of words in the quotation:

> The potency of a bubble is its plausibility, to laypeople and experts alike, right up until the moment the game is over.

This sentence means that economic bubbles are powerful because they don't look like bubbles until they pop (i.e. the market crashes).

"Game" is used as a metaphor. I suspect that this mostly refers to the fun and excitement of a game. Stoney's suggestion that it refers to gambling is also a good one.

EDIT: Elegance is a matter of opinion. The diction doesn't sound remarkable to me. Perhaps the CBC author meant that the quotation captures the essence of a bubble better than other descriptions. I'm used to thinking of elegance in terms of the scientific and technical usage, which is about graceful simplicity. Elegance also refers to a high-class, luxurious aesthetic.

[This page](http://madamedelyte.com/2014/07/07/post-the-seventy-second-how-to-cultivate-an-elegant-turn-of-phrase/) about elegance in language may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, but would you please explain what's so special or elegant about the diction of that quote?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit I tend to agree with Adam Haun about the diction; but the author may have been struck by the alliteration and assonance in "Potency is plausibility". In any case, questions of "elegance" are LitCrit and off-topic here.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for the reply and additional observation.